# Android Toolbar NavigationIcon Size

Tags: android, icons, size, toolbar

I created a toolbar in my xml file by using

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/app_bar_settings"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
      android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
      android:elevation="4dp"
    />
```

I set an NavigationIcon by using this:

```
    mToolbarSettigs.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_done_black_24dp);
```

But now there is no margin between the icon and the sides of the toolbar. 
How can I change that?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey have you come up with some answer for this problem? I'm also having this issue. This simple thing seems to be not solvable (just by design) in Android layout system. It's so ridiculous. Looks like we have to modify the icon to the appropriate size, that's so stupid.